# Titanium, Extracting info from model, sql database, and saving it to a variable

Tags: database, mobile, titanium, models

```
var manifest = Alloy.Collections.manifest;  

function submit(){
        list_view.open();

        manifest.fetch();
        var model = Alloy.createModel('manifest', {
             bill: //(need to be an incremented value),
             Num_of_elements: $.items.value 
      });

      manifest.add(model);
      model.save();
      }
```

so i have this function the when clicked it will save info the the data base, or model not to sure what the differante is yet. i want to be able to get that "Num_of_elements" value from the model at a latter time, how would i go about this. model.execute(sql query)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have the bill number you can just do this, using the [`where`](http://backbonejs.org/#Collection-where) function of backbone collections:

```
var manifest = Alloy.Collections.manifest;  
var manifest = manifest.where({
    bill : // your bill number
})[0]; // Get the first one returned
```